# How to replace bloginfo(template_url)

Tags: deprecation

Basically I've used `bloginfo(template_url)` in a WordPress theme, but when I run [theme-checker](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-check/), it recommends to replace `bloginfo(template_url)` with `get_template_directory_uri()`, however when I use `get_template_directory_uri()` it doesn't work. It works fine if I use it to replace `get_bloginfo(template_url)` but that's not what I want now. Is `bloginfo(template_url)` being deprecated? If it is, what is it's replacement?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bloginfo($option)` echos out a value whereas `get_template_directory_uri()` returns a string - did you maybe forget to echo `get_template_directory_uri()`? Also are you passing a string with quotes i.e. `bloginfo(template_url)` vs `bloginfo('template_url')`?

Both `bloginfo('template_url')` and `get_template_directory_uri()` should work, they aren't deprecated.

Comment: Firstly I do need a value rather than a string, so I'm using `bloginfo($option)`. Also, everything is working fine in my theme while using `bloginfo($option)`. The problem I have is when I use theme-checker it recommends that I should use `get_template_directory_uri()` instead, but when I did, it didn't work. Should I just ignore theme-checker's recommendation?

Comment: I would ignore it. I personally use `get_bloginfo()` over `get_template_directory_uri()` and don't see any reason why it's better to use one function over the other

Comment: Good to know! Just odd that theme-checker suggest a change that doesn't seem to be necessary... Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

`bloginfo` is a wrapper for `get_bloginfo`, which just calls those functions directly:

```
function get_bloginfo( $show = '', $filter = 'raw' ) {
    case 'stylesheet_directory':
        $output = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
        break;
    case 'template_directory':
    case 'template_url':
        $output = get_template_directory_uri();
        break;
```

so it's ultimately exactly the same output.

Answer (score 3):

This is the right way -

```
<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use both

```
<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>
```

Comment: The `echo` in front of `bloginfo()` is not needed.

Comment: yeah..thats not needed.sorry about that.its should be get_bloginfo

Comment: The code I'm using is: `<img class="big_divider" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/dividers/big_divider.png" alt="content divider" />` and is working perfectly how I wanted. The thing is that theme-checker recommends that I use `get_template_directory_uri()` instead which doesn't work when I did use it, so it made me wonder whether `bloginfo($option)` is being deprecated. If not, why is theme-checker suggesting to replace it?